# Creating an "list" of valid peripherals for my program

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Do I need to make an enum?

I want something like:

```
MyHardwareReport.Peripheral = ListOfPeripherals.Mouse
```

or

```
MyHardwareReport.Peripheral = ListOfPeripherals.Printer
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an `enum` is exactly what you need. General practice would be to name the `enum` type after the class, rather than calling it a "ListOfSomething".

```
public enum Peripheral
{
    Mouse,
    Keyboard,
    Printer
}
```